# Convert Hex integer to number (chainlink)

Tags: ethers.js, chainlink

I have a smart contract that returns the price of ETH using Chainlink. When i call getPrice() from geth i get a very large HEX number. How can i get the decimal number out of the hex value?

```
constructor (address _manager) ReentrancyGuard() {
        manager = _manager;

        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(ETH_USD_RINKENBY);
    }

function getPrice() public view returns (int) 
{        
    (
        uint80 roundID,
        int price,
        uint startedAt,
        uint timeStamp,
        uint80 answeredInRound
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();

    //uint8 decimals = priceFeed.decimals();

    return price;
}
```

returned values example

> "0xfd918bdff54b7c2d1b639fe258ea80d8f00c68e096cce9cef69b42ff6b19522d"
> "0x480f2a54bec768ccc4e97983b62925d62075fe374d2daaadfd9d686f6a2757a4"
> "0x0d30772eaf09ac3ceb1e2b80e74757ae10db37a33d9aa0cdb8df3eb228981ae5"
> "0xfb0d591bca5c552ff4ecea8c5ff52da7f7df7925ec5a1bc95ecf77d8ddd3b9d1"
> "0x0d0abf0bdeb72dd3de217d6663993c0704fe20bb124ca1caad3ba74543a23894"
> "0xfd4f9d6f754414702a7c30cc9eda7c89472c0dea1f5881557687eafef3317db4"
> "0xdb8102933cff94ee14c46d58af60e534c8eb1da3f5d1c1f9a8b18b7dacb65e56"
> "0xdc8b57ffcc0c338b912f21241fd1f4451f079dd3229ad529d798eea2b3d29350

"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using javascript you can use `parseInt`!
Not only does it take regular string numbers, it also takes hex strings!

[You can read about it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

The interface is `parseInt(string, radix)`
The second argument is the "radix" - which is a math term for essentially "base"

For your example above (taking the first hex string)
`parseInt('0xfd918bdff54b7c2d1b639fe258ea80d8f00c68e096cce9cef69b42ff6b19522d', 16)`

gives me
`1.1469230889660214e+77`

Comment: Usually it is not a good idea to use javascript numbers because they don't have enough precision to hold a uint256. Either use a library like BN.js, BigNumber.js, etc. or [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) if your js stack support them.

Comment: Great point! I will add this to the answer in a min.

Answer (score 8):

**Do not use `parseInt()`!** It has floating point errors with large numbers. You should do the following:

`BigInt(hexString).toString()`

The issue with `parseInt(hexString)` is that it outputs a number, which has a max value of `9007199254740991`. This seems large, but if you are working with `wei` in Ethereum, you know that this number is only ~0.009 Ether. Yikes!